# Read Tuple from csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I am trying to read a row in a csv, which I have previously written. 
That written row looks like this when is read: `['New York', '(30,40)']` 
and like this: `['New York', '(30,40)']` (converts the tuple in a string).

I need to read each item from the tuple to operate with the ints, but I can't if it is read like a string because if I do something like this: `tuple[0]`, what I get is: `'('` -the first character of the string tuple-

Maybe this is a question about how I write and read the rows, which actually is this way:

```
def writeCSV(data,name):
  fileName = name+'.csv'
  with open(fileName, 'a') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     writer.writerow(data)

 def readCSV(filename):
    allRows = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
       for row in reader:
          allRows.append(row)
 return allRows
```

What I want is **to read that tuple for row, not like a string, but like a tuple to operate** with each item after.
Is it possible?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` and parse the string to a tuple.

Comment: don't write a tuple in a csv row for starters. write each value on 1 row

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on you tuple string as:

```
>>> my_file_line =  ['New York', '(30,40)']
>>> import ast
>>> my_tuple = ast.literal_eval(my_file_line[1])
>>> my_tuple[0]
30
```

Because currently the list you got after reading the file at index 1 is holding the valid string of the tuple format. `ast.literal_eval` will convert your tuple string to the `tuple` object and then you can access the tuple based on the index.

Comment: That's work! This is what I need, but i take note from @Jean-FrançoisFabre to improve the writing method. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a way to read files without ast.literal_eval given memory issues associated with the ast module? For instance a tuple (1,2,3) is read as a string '(1,2,3)' when csv files are read in python

Answer (score 1):

since you're producing the file yourself, why not making it right from the start:

```
import csv

data = ['New York', (30,40)]
with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw=csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerow(data)    # wrong
    cw.writerow(data[:1]+list(data[1]))  # okay
```

the first line writes each item of `data` but tries to convert each item as `str`. `tuple` gets converted, where selecting another format could avoid this.

```
New York,"(30, 40)"
```

which explains the need to evaluate it afterwards.

The second write line writes 3 elements (now 3 columns), but preserves the data (except for the `int` part which is converted to `str` anyway)

```
New York,30,40
```

in that case, a simple string to integer conversion on rows does the job.

Note that `csv` isn't the best way to serialize mixed data. Better use `json` for that.